# С сайта приходят письма с сообщением в не той кодировке

Tags: php, кодировка

Отправляю с сайта письмо

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(!empty($_POST['contactname']) && !empty($_POST['contactemail']) && !empty($_POST['contactmessage'])) {
    $to = '****@yandex.ru'; // Your e-mail address here.
    $body = "\nName: {$_POST['contactname']}\nEmail: {$_POST['contactemail']}\n\n\n{$_POST['contactmessage']}\n\n";
    mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode("Сообщение с сайта ***.ru"),  $body, "From: {$_POST['contactemail']}"); // E-Mail subject here.
    }
}
?>
```

Тема письма отображается правильно, а в теле письма кодировка сбита, не могу понять из-за чего, пробовал по-разному. Помогите пожалуйста

Вопрос решён

```
iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1251", $body)
```

Comment: как именно оно сбито - можно только угадывать. Отправляйте английской:)

Comment: Я уже разобрался, спасибо )